# On bitbucket, is there a way to edit the commit message for squashing and merging into the develop branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit-message

I have made a few commits in the feature branch. Then I used squash to combine all the commits, and merged back to the develop branch.

However, I want to edit the commit message (on BitBucket) since it uses the exact same wording from my last squash commit from feature to the develop branch.

Is it possible to 1) edit my commit message for the squash merge into the develop commit? Or 2) somehow combine my last two squash merge into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`develop` is a shared branch. You must not rewrite the history of a shared branch, because that will make the lives of the other people who share the branch a misery. Editing a commit message, or combining two merge commits, rewrites history. So don't do either of those things.